# What is the right way to enable odata controller in asp.net core?

Tags: controller, odata, asp.net-core

There is no `HttpConfiguration` accessible, so I can't use this code.

```
        config.MapHttpAttributeRoutes();

        var builder = new ODataConventionModelBuilder();
        builder.EntitySet<Client>("clients");

        config.Routes.MapODataServiceRoute("ODataRoute", "odata", builder.GetEdmModel());
```

What is the right way to enable odata controllers in asp.net core?

Answer (score 2):

As far as I know there is no full OData support on vnext yet.

You can track the progress via the myget repository:

http://myget.org/gallery/odatavnext